# Robocopy copy only changed files to new folder

Tags: windows-7, backup, batch, robocopy

I'd like to create a backup such as the following:
C:/backups/20140101/    All files from source folder
C:/backups/20140102/    Only files changed since last backup
C:/backups/20140103/    Only files changed since last backup

So somewhat like robocopy, but with a different output folder.

At the moment i'm copying everything every time which is rather time inefficient (and space, but that is less of an issue).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robocopy has an option `/maxage` and that checks the last modification date on files that you are copying.

For example if you need to copy only files that have changed since the last backup (1 day ago)

```
robocopy sourcepath destpath /maxage:1
```

Comment: This works; I neglected to consider that by running a scheduled backup that I could use a defined variable for maxage.